# Topological Subspace Criterion Translated to Condition on Bases (Wilansky Problem 6 Sec 2.6)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $B_1, B_2$ be bases for topologies $T_1, T_2$ on a given set. Show that

$T_1 \subseteq T_2 \iff$ for every point $x$ and $V \in B_1$ with $x \in V$, $\exists \ W \in B_2$ with $x \in W \subseteq V$

I'm curious if the following proof is valid (more elegant proofs, etc. welcome as well).

**Proof Attempt**

$(\implies)$
We have

$V \in B_1 \implies V \in T_1 \implies V \in T_2$.

This shows $V$ is neighborhood of $x$ relative to $T_2$, now the result follows since $B_2$ contains a base at $x$.

$(\impliedby)$ Suppose $Y \in T_1$. Then for each $x \in Y$, there is an open set  $G_x \subseteq Y$ containing $x$. Since $G_x$ is open, it the union of some elements in $B_1$, and hence there is some $V_x \in B_1$ such that $x \in V_x \subseteq G_x$.

By hypothesis we can find $W_x \in B_2$ such that $x \in W_x \subseteq V_x \subseteq Y$. This shows that $Y$ is a $T_2$ neighborhood of each of its points and hence $Y \in T_2$.

$\square$

**Background/Context**

This is Problem 6 Sec. 2.6 from Albert Wilansky's $\textit{Topology for Analysis}$. I'm self studying this book coming from an analysis background. I haven't found solutions online. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but the second part can be simplified just a little by going directly to $V_x$. If $Y\in T_1$, then for each $x\in Y$ there is a $V_x\in B_1$ such that $x\in V_x\subseteq Y$. By hypothesis there is a $W_x\in B_2$ such that $x\in W_x\subseteq V_x\subseteq Y$, so $Y=\bigcup_{x\in Y}W_x\in T_2$.